# Passbook web services to update a pass

Tags: node.js, passbook

I have created a web service to update our passbooks with the following entries in my routes file:

// Registering a Device to Receive Push Notifications for a Pass
app.post('/Passbook/v1/devices/:dli/registrations/:typeid/:serial', PBAdmin.registerDevice);

// Getting the Serial Numbers for Passes Associated with a Device
app.get('/Passbook/v1/devices/:dli/registrations/:typeid',PBAdmin.getSerialNumbers);

// Getting the Latest Version of a Pass
app.get('/Passbook/v1/passes/:typeid/:serial', PBAdmin.getUpdatedPass);

// Unregistering a Device
app.delete('/Passbook/v1/devices/:dli/registrations/:typeid/:serial', PBAdmin.unregisterDevice);

// Logging Errors
app.post('/Passbook/v1/log', PBAdmin.logErrors);

The problem is that after a passbook is downloaded by a user my web service end point receives a GET request instead of POST request for registering a device (from my log file)

GET /Passbook/v1/devices/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxe99ddc69a5a9/registrations/xxx.xxxx.xxxx.app.dev.passbook/1408646948910 401 18ms - 12b

In fact this happens for the log handler as well (which is supposed to be POST with error message). I am not sure why that is and how to fix it.

Comment: It turns out my HAProxy was misconfigured. Fixing HAProxy fixed the issue.

Comment: hi @user3083637 i also have the same issue.. actually i have no idea about how to update the pass from a server. i have read the documentation but still im confused. can you tell me how to do that ?